# How do you share implementation details in a functional language like rust?

Tags: functional-programming, rust

I sometimes find myself writing abstract classes with partial implementation in C#:

```
abstract public class Executor {
    abstract protected bool Before();
    abstract protected bool During();
    abstract protected bool After();
    protected bool Execute() {
         var success = false;
         if (Before()) {
              if (During()) {
                  if (After()) {
                        success = true;
                  }
              }
         }
         return success;
    }
}
```

Notwithstanding the wisdom of such a control structure, how would I accomplish this (partial shared implementation) in a functional language like rust?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using default methods on traits is one way (and will probably/hopefully be the idiomatic way in the future; until recently, the `struct`-with-closures method @Slartibartfast demonstrates was the only thing that actually worked):

```
#[allow(default_methods)];

trait Executable {
   fn before(&self) -> bool;
   fn during(&self) -> bool;
   fn after(&self) -> bool; 

   fn execute(&self) -> bool {
      self.before() && self.during() && self.after()
   }
}

impl Executable for int {
   fn before(&self) -> bool { *self < 10 }
   fn during(&self) -> bool { *self < 5 }
   fn after(&self) -> bool { *self < 0 }

   // execute is automatically supplied, if it is not implemented here
}
```

Note that it is possible for an implementation of `Executable` to override `execute` at the moment (I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/7649) about a `#[no_override]` attribute that would disable this).

Also, default methods are experimental and prone to crashing the compiler (yes, more so than the rest of Rust), but they are improving quickly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not within reach of a rust compiler, so forgive broken code.

On a functional side of things, you could make a struct that holds three functions and invoke them

```
struct Execution {
    before: @fn() -> bool,
    during: @fn() -> bool,
    after: @fn() -> bool
}

fn execute (e: Execution) -> bool {
  ...
}
```

but once you have a function as a first class value, you could pass say, a list of boolean functions to check against instead of fixed three, or something else depending on what are you trying to achieve.

On a rust side of things, you can make it more "object oriented" by using traits

```
trait Executable {
    fn execute(&self);
}

impl Execution {
    fn execute(&self) {
        ...
    }
}
```